# What can limit device other than UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

I just found out that my app on TestFlight is only compatible with iPad Air and Mini, and not iPad 4th gen. I'm trying to figure out why that is.

In the project's info.plist, the only device requirement I have is armv7, which is compatible with all recent iPad models. What else should I check for to figure out why iPad 4th gens and below aren't compatible?

Comment: Did you try to install it on iPad 4th gen? Is it allowed by TestFlight? Could be that apple just lists the most recent iPad of each idiom, without enumerating all of them.

Comment: I am able to install on my iPad 3rd gen, but when it goes on TestFlight, I am unable to install. I invited myself, and TestFlight said my iPad was incompatible.